# Spool the data from a CLOB

Tags: oracle, plsqldeveloper

I have the result of several CLOB, (about 100 Clob). I want to to extract all the data in the CLOB in one one script. I searched for spool but for now I didnt how to use it .

Example: select info from ex_employee where data <15

> INFO
>   < CLOB > 
>   < CLOB > 
>   < CLOB > 
>   < CLOB > 
>   < CLOB >

those CLOB contain informations how can I spool them into a script example.sql?

My PROBLEM IS : How to export the CLOB data into .sql ?

I tried this way 
Spool on
set heading off
Spool c:\spooltext.txt
select dbms_metadata.get_ddl('TABLE', table_name)
from user_tables
/
Spool off

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name PL/SQL developer. I tried this way ------- Spool on
set heading off
Spool c:\spooltext.txt
select dbms_metadata.get_ddl('TABLE', table_name)
from user_tables
/
Spool off 
 but its giving me errors

Comment: :Can you please update your question with what you tried?

Comment: So what is the error?  We are not mind readers.

Comment: @OldProgrammer you can re- read my question

Comment: @Moudiz :Please post the error when you execute the script

Comment: @GauravSoni When I run it in sql windown it throw me an error: Invalid sql statement. IF I run it in command window, the query works fine but it display the half query ( create table abc ( v nmbr, .. and it stop here ) so I am searching for a way that I can extract the data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this ,because it work for me in toad

```
SET HEADING OFF
SET PAGESIZE 0
SET LONG 90000
SET FEEDBACK OFF
SET ECHO OFF
SPOOL P:\other\file_name.sql

SELECT DBMS_METADATA.get_ddl ('TABLE', table_name) || ';' FROM user_tables;

SPOOL OFF
```

And this works in command prompt too

Comment: the problem with this it wwill not give me all the constraint .. i tried it.